# Thread 1: SIGABRT Error when testing FB Login in XCODE

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook

So I am running a quick test of my Facebook login feature through a simulator on Xcode (latest version) and every time I click my "Login with Facebook" button, the app crashes on the simulator and gives me a Thread 1: SIGABRT Error and highlights the following code in my app delegate.swift file

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

EDIT: I also received the same error when attempting to run the app my iPhone

EDIT: Here is what the error log gave me when I clicked the Login Button

> StudyBuddy[1139:22725] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'fb123961701329868 is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist'

I understand that the fb123961701329868 is my app ID but how do I implement this as a URL scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I dug around on a few places and the key is to go to the info.plist and add an array called **URL TYPES** and under **ITEM 0** change from **URL Identifier** to **URL Schemes** and under **ITEM 0** for the scheme put in the Facebook App ID prefixed by "fb" in order to ensure proper URL call back.